# KnownFolders ask for permission everytime app runs on insider build

Tags: uwp, windows-10, file-permissions, known-folders, storagefolder

the upcoming version of **Windows 10** has this new system where when the **uwp** app has the **capabiity** of any library like **Video Library**, it tried to make the user more secure by asking for permission with a prompt dialog, so we can use the Video Library only if the user allows the app. This feature is secure and good for the user, but the problem is that everytime the user runs the app the app asks about using the **video library** which is not a good experience even for the user, so what is the work around for this that if the user allows the app on the first run that the app can use his video library, then the app should somehow store those settings and let the app use their video library on every next run without asking the permissions everytime.

> an example to use the video library is with following code

```
KnownFolders.VideoLibrary
```

Comment: This extra prompting behaviour is being removed from the final release of the next Windows 10 update.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT so in the final release it will work just like it used to work before? I just have to specify the videoLibrary capability and then I can just use KnownFolders.VideoLibrary without any prompts to the user?

Comment: Yes, there should be no prompt. Note that the prompts might come back in a future update to Windows, but they should only prompt once, not every time the app starts.

Comment: yeah one time prompt seems perfect. Thanks for the clarifiction @PeterTorr-MSFT please put this as answer so that I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These prompts were introduce in "Insider" builds of the RS4 (Spring 2018) Windows 10 update, but they are being removed from the final release due to some issues (like this one). The final General Availability (GA) release of the Spring update will not have these prompts.

A future release of Windows might re-introduce these prompts to improve users' control over their privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the [videosLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) capability in your app's manifest?

If your app has this capability, it should show up as the permissions required in the store listing, but not prompt on every usage.

Otherwise, as you've seen, every time you try and use a restricted area, it will ask the user for permission.  Though, I'm not sure if you added the known folder to your [future access list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions) if it would prompt you on future usages, it's usually best to declare the capability in this situation.

Comment: Yes I have declared the capability, and uptil fall creators update I didnt get any prompt but they have added the prompt in the upcoming version as I am on insiders build right now so I get the prompt